# Sort and take top five values of hash

Tags: ruby

I have a hash whose keys are unique but values similar. I am trying to retrieve pairs of the top five highest values. For example, from this:

```
{9=>1, 11=>1, 12=>2, 13=>1, 14=>1, 18=>1, 19=>1, 20=>1, 23=>1, 24=>2, 27=>1, 28=>1, 29=>1, 30=>1, 33=>1, 34=>1, 35=>1, 36=>1, 37=>1, 38=>1, 39=>1, 40=>1, 41=>1, 42=>1, 43=>1, 44=>1, 45=>1, 46=>1, 47=>1, 48=>1, 49=>1, 52=>1, 53=>1, 54=>1, 55=>1, 56=>1, 57=>1, 58=>1, 59=>1, 60=>1, 61=>1, 62=>1, 63=>1, 64=>1, 66=>1, 67=>1, 68=>1, 69=>1, 70=>2, 72=>1}
```

I would like these values first

```
=> 12=>2, 24=>2, 70=>2, ???
```

I am not sure how to do this because there are three instances whose value is `2`. How would ruby decide what the next values are if they are all the same?

I have this solution

```
@common_locations.max { |a,b| a.last() <=> b.last() }
```

but this only gives me one instance. How would I collect five?

Comment: Sort and take the top five?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes!, apologies incorrect question title!

Comment: There is no hash whose keys are not unique.

Comment: What is `@common_locations`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
hash = {9=>1, 11=>1, 12=>2, 13=>1, 14=>1, 18=>1, 19=>1, 20=>1, 23=>1, 24=>2, 27=>1, 28=>1, 29=>1, 30=>1, 33=>1, 34=>1, 35=>1, 36=>1, 37=>1, 38=>1, 39=>1, 40=>1, 41=>1, 42=>1, 43=>1, 44=>1, 45=>1, 46=>1, 47=>1, 48=>1, 49=>1, 52=>1, 53=>1, 54=>1, 55=>1, 56=>1, 57=>1, 58=>1, 59=>1, 60=>1, 61=>1, 62=>1, 63=>1, 64=>1, 66=>1, 67=>1, 68=>1, 69=>1, 70=>2, 72=>1}

hash.sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse.first(5).to_h
#=> {12=>2, 70=>2, 24=>2, 44=>1, 67=>1}
```

You can replace `sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse` with `sort_by { |k, v| -v }` if your values are numbers.

Note that `Array#to_h` was introduced in Ruby 2.1; for older versions, you will have to use `Hash[hash.sort_by...first(5)]` instead.

Comment: in this case you could sort by -v and skip the `reverse` step. Also, you can't call `to_h` on an Array; you need to pass it to `Hash[`...`]` instead: `Hash[hash.sort_by{|k,v|-v}.first(5)]`.